# Preselect uib-btn-radio button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following btn-group

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-success active" data-ng-model="myModel" uib-btn-radio="'enabled'"  data-ng-click="vm.myFunction()">
           Enabled
       </label>
       <label class="btn btn-success" data-ng-model="myModel" uib-btn-radio="'disabled'" data-ng-click="vm.myFunction()">
            Disabled
        </label>
 </div>
```

When the page is been displeyed angular adds two classes ng-pristine and ng-untouched and remove class active from the first radio button like the following.

```
<label class="btn btn-success ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid waves-effect" data-ng-model="vm.statusFilter" uib-btn-radio="'enabled'" data-ng-click="vm.filterGridByStatus()">
    Enabled
</label>
```

Comment: If you are asking how to make one of your radio buttons have focus when the form renders, this might help: https://github.com/hiebj/ng-focus-if

Comment: you use 2 different sources for the model, fyi.  I wonder if that's whats causing your problem (eg - neither button is active because one's linked to vm.myModel and the other is linked to just myModel).  Just a thought...

Answer (score 4):

Let the directive handle the active state. In your controller, assign the active button to the model.

```
$scope.myModel = 'enabled';
```

http://codepen.io/tsneville/pen/aNWoNd

Answer (score 0):

You can select using ng-class.

HTML...

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-TopSubform">
                <label ng-class="buttonSelectedInButtonGrp" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Left'">Primary Location1</label>
                <label class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Middle'">Other Locations</label>
            </div>
```

Angular Controller (or could be shifted into a directive) ...

```
$scope.buttonSelectedInButtonGrp = "btn btn-lg btn-success ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty active ng-not-empty ng-valid-parse";
```

Note that this is different to the unselected class list which is...
btn btn-lg btn-success ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty

The css can be edited as...

```
.btn-success.active {
        border-color:darkblue;
        border-width:medium;
}

.btn-success {
    border-color:none;
    border-width:medium;

}
```